# angular matcheck disable after reloading

Tags: angular, checkbox, disable

I have a matcheck in my angular app. I am disabling the checkbox based on some condition. it works when the screen loads initially.
There is a scenario, where on click of a button, a mat-dialog is open. when I click 'CANCEl' , on mat-dialog, I still call disableChkBox method, but the checkbox is enabled.

```
          <mat-checkbox style="padding-top: 0px;" [disabled]="disableChkBox()"   formControlName = "mycheckbox" value = "cbx1" id = "mycheckbox"  checked = "false">
          <mat-label>Include Average ratio</mat-label></mat-checkbox>
          
          <button mat-raised-button id="btn" color="primary"   (click)="displayConfirmDialog()">Dialog Open</button>

Component.ts    

      disableChkBox() {          
          if(this.myform.controls['name'].value === 'dave' && (this.apprepubForm.get('age').value === '45') {
           return true;
          } else {  
            return false;
          }
        }
       

       displayConfirmDialog() { 
       
               dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res) => {
                this.disableChkBox();
             })
       }
```

Comment: looks like you are missing and end parenthesis on your if statement, might be causing you errors and odd behavior